# Use a Object by String?

Tags: java

Is it possible to use a Object if i only got the String? I have an Object 'John' from the Class 'Student'. In the Class 'Student' is a ArrayList 'friends'. I want to access the Object 'John' by using a String (the name of the object). (Line 2 in the example)

```
 public void addFriend(Student student, String friend) throws IOException{
        student.friends.add(friend);
        System.out.println("Friend: " + friend + " added to List of " + student);
    }
```

I hope you understand what i mean (i am sorry for my terrible english :/ )

Comment: I think you'll want to make a constructor for the class Student that accepts a string as a parameter. Than in the function "addFriend" construct a student object, add the newly created object to the student's list of friends and overload the class Student's toString method so you can easily print it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map for this problem.

```
Map<String, Student> friends = new HashMap<String, Student>();
friends.put("John", objectOfJohn);
Student target = friends.get("John");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to print out name of a student using the variable student. If this is the case, you may want to override the `toString()` method inside Student class which returns name of that student. For example:

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // ... Other methods

    // here is the toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this to print out the student name:

```
System.out.println("Friend: " + friend + " added to List of " + student.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Student` Class and you have created in some point some objects of this class.

```
Student john = new Student();
Student mike= new Student();
Student mary = new Student();
```

and you have all these objects stored in an `Arraylist` allStudents

```
ArrayList<Student > allStudents= new ArrayList<>();
allStudents.add(john);
allStudents.add(mike);
allStudents.add(mary);
```

So, if you want to find `john` from this list you may do:

**Option A**

If the name for your case is unique and exists also as an attribute in your object, you can iterate the `Arraylist` and find it:

```
Student getStudentByName = new Student();
for(Student student : allStudents){
   if(student.getName().equals("john")){ //If name is unique
       getStudentByName = student;
   }
}
```

**Option B**

Add all objects in `HashMap`

```
Map<String, Student> allStudents= new HashMap<>();
allStudents.put("john", john);
allStudents.put("mike", mike);
allStudents.put("mary", mary);
```

And then get your desired object by:

```
Student target = friends.get("john");
```

Be mind that if you add again :

```
allStudents.put("john", newStudentObject);
```

the `HashMap` will keep the last entry.